# ansible playbook for kubernetes using sudo elevation role not finding the shell script file location

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am trying to join in some of my kubernetes nodes to the cluster however the shell script used by the user marlon requires privilege escalation which then is not finding the file's location

both nodes have copied the file correctly to tmp folder by the playbook

```
marlon@node1:/tmp$ ll join-command.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 marlon marlon 169 Oct  1 09:40 join-command.sh*
marlon@node2:/tmp$ ll join-command.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 marlon marlon 169 Oct  1 09:41 join-command.sh*
```

however whenever trying to run the playbook with the correct privileges I am getting the following error:

```
TASK [kubernetes : Join the node to cluster] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [node1.madebeen.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "./tmp/join-command.sh", "delta": "0:00:00.002299", "end": "2021-10-01 09:40:50.377483", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-10-01 09:40:50.375184", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: ./tmp/join-command.sh: not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: ./tmp/join-command.sh: not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal: [node2.madebeen.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "./tmp/join-command.sh", "delta": "0:00:00.003164", "end": "2021-10-01 09:40:50.394857", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-10-01 09:40:50.391693", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: ./tmp/join-command.sh: not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: ./tmp/join-command.sh: not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

here is the playbook's configuration:

```
- name: Copy the join command to server location
    become_user: marlon
    copy: src=join-command dest=/tmp/join-command.sh mode=0777
    
  - name: Join the node to cluster
    become_method: su
    become_user: marlon
    shell: ./tmp/join-command.sh
```

I've also tried to set become: yes but then the privileged user (root) couldn't find the file...

```
fatal: [node1.madebeen.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "./tmp/join-command.sh", "delta": "0:00:00.002299", "end": "2021-10-01 09:45:50.377483", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-10-01 09:40:50.375184", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: ./tmp/join-command.sh: not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: ./tmp/join-command.sh: not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal
```

I also tried to use command: sh ./tmp/join-command.sh

```
fatal: [node1.madebeen.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sh", "./tmp/join-command.sh"], "delta": "0:00:00.001923", "end": "2021-10-01 09:54:05.662220", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-10-01 09:54:05.660297", "stderr": "sh: 0: Can't open ./tmp/join-command.sh", "stderr_lines": ["sh: 0: Can't open ./tmp/join-command.sh"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal: [node2.madebeen.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sh", "./tmp/join-command.sh"], "delta": "0:00:00.001988", "end": "2021-10-01 09:54:05.683108", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-10-01 09:54:05.681120", "stderr": "sh: 0: Can't open ./tmp/join-command.sh", "stderr_lines": ["sh: 0: Can't open ./tmp/join-command.sh"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

and didn't work either

```
fatal: [node1.madebeen.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sh", "./tmp/join-command.sh"], "delta": "0:00:00.001923", "end": "2021-10-01 09:54:05.662220", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-10-01 09:54:05.660297", "stderr": "sh: 0: Can't open ./tmp/join-command.sh", "stderr_lines": ["sh: 0: Can't open ./tmp/join-command.sh"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal: [node2.madebeen.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sh", "./tmp/join-command.sh"], "delta": "0:00:00.001988", "end": "2021-10-01 09:54:05.683108", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-10-01 09:54:05.681120", "stderr": "sh: 0: Can't open ./tmp/join-command.sh", "stderr_lines": ["sh: 0: Can't open ./tmp/join-command.sh"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

went through several other threads on this but couldn't find a definitive answer on it...
any thoughts?

I have also tried to remove the . in front of the directory but still didn't work out... #middlewareinventory.com/blog/…

```
 - name: Join the node to cluster 
   #become_user: marlon 
   #become_method: 
   sudo become: yes 
   shell: /tmp/join-command.sh
```

Comment: read the following article which should do the trick here but it didn't...
https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-sudo-ansible-become-example/

Comment: I have also tried to remove the . in front of the directory but still didn't work out...
#https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-sudo-ansible-become-example/
  - name: Join the node to cluster
    #become_user: marlon
    #become_method: sudo
    become: yes
    shell: /tmp/join-command.sh

Comment: It is higly suspicious that your `ll` command appends a `*` at the end of that  `join-command.sh`. I suspect you shipped those files in an odd manner and ended with some sort of corrupted file names.

Comment: Also, please, by all means, *do not* use comments to add bits of code or extra information, rather [edit] your original question to add those informations in.

Answer (score 1):

Got it work with the following:

https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-sudo-ansible-become-example/

```
  - name: Join the node to cluster
    #become_user: marlon
    #become_method: sudo
    #become: yes
    shell: |
      kubeadm reset --force
      /tmp/join-command.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here

```
shell: ./tmp/join-command.sh
```

You are using a relative path, that's why it can not be found.
You should use a full path.
try

```
shell: /tmp/join-command.sh
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/

Comment: hey I just tried removing that . and still didn't work out I am afraid

TASK [kubernetes : Join the node to cluster]

fatal: [node2.madebeen.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/tmp/join-command.sh", "delta": "0:00:00.071751", "end": "2021-10-01 14:05:17.483612", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-10-01 14:05:17.411861", "stderr": "error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:\n\t[ERROR IsPrivilegedUser]: user is not running as root\n[preflight]

Comment: Now that's a different error. It clearly says that you need to run as root.

Comment: I changed the playbook to reflect that new output to the following...

```code
  - name: Join the node to cluster
    become: yes
    shell: /tmp/join-command.sh 
```
but still didn't work... incredible....
[ERROR IsPrivilegedUser]: user is not running as root\n[preflight]